# Point to integer conversion

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a plot p1, and I am extracting the points where it intersects the x-axis by

```
Cases[Normal[p1], Point[___], {1, Infinity}]
```

It returns the output

{Point[{6760.63, 0.}], Point[{-3086.13, 0.}]}

Now I want to extract the two x co-ordinates from the two points and subtract them, how should I convert point to an integer.

Comment: Add this in the begining of your code  `Subtract @@ First @@@`

Comment: @J42161217 Thanks it worked, but what is this doing? Also how do i extract the two points separately as integers?

Comment: try only `First@@@` to get x-coordinates or `First/@` to get xy